# a terminal emulator w/key-customization on par with iTerm?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, vim

I've (mostly) migrated from macOS to linux, and I really miss the ability to configure custom key sequences in my terminal emulator. iTerm lets you map a keyboard shortcut to send ansi escape sequences. I used this to do things like distinguish Shift+Enter from plain Enter, allowing me to define a vim mapping for Shift+Enter.

I'm currently using gnome-terminal, and though it's configurable up to a point, it doesn't seem to let you do what I want (please correct me if I'm wrong about that).

Is there a terminal emulator that runs on linux and allows this kind of flexibility in defining custom keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Konsole has this section in its *Edit profile* settings:

[image]

I haven't experimented with it, but it looks like it might fit your needs.